# Defining a schema based on a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I'd like to create a quiz app, and store the results in a single collection (let's say 'QuizResults'). I'd also like admins to be able to create 'quiz templates', which could be stored in a collection (let's say 'QuizTemplates'). Admins should be able to 'assign' specific quizzes to specific users and I'll track these assignments in a third collection (let's say 'QuizAssignments').

In the QuizAssignments collection, each document will have the 'AssignedTo' user reference, and the 'TemplateForQuiz' as a reference to the 'QuizTemplates' collection.

Each QuizResults document should have the QuizAssignment reference, and the QuizTemplate reference, but the rest of the document should be dictated by the template.

As an example of what I'm thinking - trying to simplify so not written out properly:

```
QuizTemplates:
  QuizTemplate1:
    Labels: ["What is 2+2?", "How do you say happy birthday in French?"]
    Formats: [Number, String]

  QuizTemplate2:
    Labels: ["How do you say happy birthday in German?", "What is 3+3?"]
    Formats: [String, Number]

QuizAssignments:
  User: Reference - User model
  QuizTemplate: Reference - QuizTemplates model

QuizResults:
  User: Reference - User model
  AssignedIn: Reference - QuizAssignments model
  Template: Reference - QuizAssignments model

/* for (let i = 0; i < this.template.Labels; i++) {
     let qnNo = `${i + 1}`;
     this["question" + i] = {};
     this["question" + i].label = this.template.Labels[i];
     this["question" + i].type = this.template.Formats[i];
} */
```

Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One benefit of having mongodb is the fact you don't need any specific schema. So your approach looks more like in a rational database.

You could do it as following:

```
QuizTemplates:
 1:
  Name: First template
  Questions: 
   1:
    Label:"What is 2+2?"
    Format: Number
   2:
    Label: "How do you say happy birthday in French?"]
    Format: String
 2:
  Name: Second template
  Questions: 
   1:
    Label:"What is 3+3?"
    Format: Number
   2:
    Label: "How do you say happy birthday in German?"]
    Format: String

Quizzes:
 1:
  User: Reference - User model
  answers:
   1: 
    Label: How do you say happy birthday in German?
    Answer: Alles Gute zum Geburtstag
   2: 
    Label: What is 3+3?
    Answer: 9
```

You can simply embed your answers as embedded documents. Moreover you don't have to store explicitly the format. It only matters to display the input, but that's stored in the template anyway. The template needs no extra reference because changing a template does not affect the results. If you like you can record the name or the id for data analysis.

A good start is reading the documentation of mongodb about data modeling https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Comment: So if you don't mind me summarising (and risking putting words in your mouth): 1. Forget about the schema for the results; 2. Use the QuizTemplate document to configure the form; 3. Insert whatever data comes from the form into the Results document under a particular key; 
Is that about right?

Comment: 1. Yes, your app is responsible to handle the data properly. For example you could have a ruby on rails app. The implementation of the models there is responsible for validation and structure. 2. Yes. 3. Yes at it said in 1. that's the task of your application not the database.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure I understood properly.